# Fitnesse test suite with variables

Tags: testing, fitnesse, suite

Is it possible to set up a variable within the test suite so that it can be passed down to the setup fit page as a parameter value?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Use a !define xxx {yyy} on the suite page and a ${xxx} on the SetUp page.  Make sure the SetUp page and all the test pages are children of the Suite page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the FlowFixture, this contains the keyword name.

More info at: http://www.syterra.com/FitnesseDotNet/NameKeyword.html